# How i can read xml into DataTable type object?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, datatable, dataset

I don't have problem if i read xml to `DataSet`:

```
DataSet temp = new DataSet();
temp.ReadXml(UncompressedStream, System.Data.XmlReadMode.Auto);
```

But if i use `DataTable`:

```
DataTable temp = new DataTable();
temp.ReadXml(UncompressedStream);
```

then datatable not load data (count of columns and rows equal 0 )

How i can read xml to `DataTable`

My temporary solution:

```
DataSet temp = new DataSet();
DataTable structure = new DataTable();
temp.ReadXml(UncompressedStream, System.Data.XmlReadMode.Auto);
structure = temp.Tables[0];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private static void DemonstrateReadWriteXMLDocumentWithString()
{
    DataTable table = CreateTestTable("XmlDemo");
    PrintValues(table, "Original table");

    string fileName = "C:\\TestData.xml";
    table.WriteXml(fileName, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);

    DataTable newTable = new DataTable();
    newTable.ReadXml(fileName);

    // Print out values in the table.
    PrintValues(newTable, "New table");
}

private static DataTable CreateTestTable(string tableName)
{
    // Create a test DataTable with two columns and a few rows.
    DataTable table = new DataTable(tableName);
    DataColumn column = new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32));
    column.AutoIncrement = true;
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    column = new DataColumn("item", typeof(System.String));
    table.Columns.Add(column);

    // Add ten rows.
    DataRow row;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        row = table.NewRow();
        row["item"] = "item " + i;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    table.AcceptChanges();
    return table;
}
```

This is from: [microsoft - xml - datatable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs0z9zxd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Check that in this code, they add a name for the table, and create the rows and the columns.

Answer (score 0):

[LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) may be a thing you are rather looking for.